# Evitar valores duplicados en un set de objetos

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito almacenar una serie de elementos en una lista pero que no estén duplicados. Para facilitarme el trabajo estoy utilizando `personalACargo: Set<Empleado> = new Set()` pero estoy obteniendo valores duplicados. Esto no me pasa si el tipo es `string`.

Los datos los agrego de esta manera:

```js
 agregarPersonalACargo(dato: Dato) {
    if (!dato) return;
    this.personalACargo.add(<Empleado> dato.objeto);
  }
```

Aun así no entiendo por que cuando obtengo valores desde la BD los agrega duplicados. Se que el set no almacena duplicados pero no encuentro la manera de evitar este comportamiento.

Dejo un ejemplo [funcional que replica el comportamiento](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bamevc).

---

***EDICIÓN***

Según este ejemplo sacado de [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set#Ejemplos):

```
const o = {a: 1, b: 2};
mySet.add(o);

mySet.add({a: 1, b: 2}); // La variable "o" referencia a otro objeto, por lo que agrega otro valor.
```

Al parecer lo que estoy buscando hacer no se puede lograr por que el `set` compara  la referencia del objeto.

Comment: Es que para JS no existen dos objetos iguales. Por eso SET nunca elimina objetos con las mismas propiedades.

Comment: Segun la documentacion deberia hacerlo: `'El objeto Set te permite almacenar valores únicos de cualquier tipo, incluso valores primitivos u objetos de referencia.'`

Comment: Exacto, pero para JS dos objetos con las mismas propiedades son idénticos pero no iguales, por lo que para un Set son diferentes.

Comment: Yo tenia objetos con una unica propiedad cuando me tope con tu problema, por lo que lo solucione pasando todos los objetos a un Array y ahi le aplique el set. Con el resultado sin duplicados, volvi a convertir

Comment: Que sentido tiene convertir a `set` si lo tienes que limpiar como un `Array`?

Comment: Debes usar dos array uno para guardar los datos en general y luego con el SET lo traspasas a otro array en el cual se pasaran sin duplicados, 1.- Es mejor manera de trabajar con datos, 2.- Con esa intencion se genero el metodo SET.

Comment: @OrlandoAguilera No quita los duplicados en este caso. Checa el ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que cuando agregas otro objeto, para el set es completamente diferente, pues así el contenido del objeto sea igual al que uno que esté almacenado, la referencia de memoria son distintas, es exactamente el siguiente caso:

```js
const objeto_1 = { nombre: 'oscar' };
const objeto_2 = { nombre: 'oscar' };

console.log('¿Son iguales?: ' + ( objeto_1 === objeto_2 ));
```

Si seguimos el ejemplo de la documentación que muestras, mira que si intentamos agregar el objeto "o" varias veces nunca lo va a agregar, pero si intentamos insertar otro con el mismo contenido si:

*Para ver el contenido de mySet correctamente visualizar desde la consola del navegador.*

```js
const mySet = new Set();

mySet.add(1);
mySet.add(5);
mySet.add('some text');

const o = {a: 1, b: 2};
mySet.add(o);

// mostramos lo que hay en el set
console.log(mySet);

// intentamos agregar a "o" de nuevo
mySet.add(o);
mySet.add(o);
mySet.add(o);

// mostramos lo que hay en el set
console.log(mySet);

// insertamos otro objeto con el "mismo valor"
mySet.add({a: 1, b: 2});

// mostramos lo que hay en el set
console.log(mySet);
```

Te recomiendo que mejor uses un arreglo y valides si contiene un objeto en específico con el método **find()**, así:

```js
// suponiendo que es una propiedad de tu clase
let personalACargo = [];

personalACargo.push({ nombre: 'oscar' });
personalACargo.push({ nombre: 'maria' });

function agregarPersonalACargo(dato) {
    if (!personalACargo.find(p => p.nombre === dato.nombre)) {
      personalACargo.push(dato);
    }
}

// imprimimos información actual
console.log({ personalACargo });

// intentamos agregar a oscar de nuevo...
agregarPersonalACargo({ nombre: 'oscar' });

// imprimimos información actual
console.log({ personalACargo });
```